# How to localize iOS 8 Today Widget?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, notificationcenter, today-extension

I am trying to localize my iOS 8 Today center widget.

I have a storyboard specifically for the widget and hit the localize button and selected Spanish. The same way I localized the normal part of the app. As you can see here:

[image: Storyboard setup]

The files have the following settings with Target Membership set to my extension:

[image: Linking]

No matter what I try (using .strings or individual .storyboards for each language or even setting the NSLocalizedStrings through code), I cannot get the language to show up correctly localized in the notification center widget. Everything works as expected in the regular app. Anyone have any experience or thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those experiencing the same problem, I had to delete the storyboard and rebuild a new one. Localizing this seemed to work.